# Silverlight: Use TransitioningContentControl to animate a grid from read-only to edit mode

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, transition

I am using Silverlight 4.0 and I have a simple grid in which some user related details are shown, like name, phone no. address, etc.
Initially the textboxes are in read-only mode.
Textboxes become editable when a user clicks on "Update Info" link (in the same grid).
Now I am trying out a simple transition effect from "read-only" to "editable" mode..

here's the xaml code

```
 <layoutToolkit:TransitioningContentControl x:Name="tcc"
                                               Grid.Row="1"
                                               BorderThickness="1">
        <layoutToolkit:TransitioningContentControl.Content>
            <Grid x:Name="grd1" Background="White">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="Name" Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0"/>

                <TextBox x:Name="txtName" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>

                <TextBlock Text="Email" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="0"/>

                <TextBox x:Name="txtEmail" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
                <Button x:Name="ChangeContent" Content="Updatee Info" Click="ChangeContent_Click" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"></Button>
            </Grid>
        </layoutToolkit:TransitioningContentControl.Content>
    </layoutToolkit:TransitioningContentControl>
```

and in the button click event

```
private void ChangeContent_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //tcc.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString();
       txtName.IsReadOnly = false;
       txtEmail.IsReadOnly = false;           
    }
```

How can I achieve a transition effect in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not much familiar with `TransitioningContentControl`, but I think for that control to work, you need to switch the `Content` itself and not just a property of a `Control` inside it. To achieve the needed transition, you can create a custom (or modify existing) `ControlTemplate` for the textbox with a custom `VisualState` named 'ReadOnly' and a `Storyboard` in it for the needed effect. Or you can create two different `Grid` controls, one with `ReadOnly` interface and one with `Editable` interface and in your code, just switch between them.

The following link has a working example on how to use `TransitioningContentControl` : http://firstfloorsoftware.com/blog/animated-page-navigation-in-sl3/

Comment: Thanks for reading the post and yes you are right..the content needs to be changed.
This is how I managed to get the animation effect:-
in the click event of the link, first I set the content of TCC to null, then I changed the visibility of controls and at the end assign the grid back to the content of TCC.
and right now, I am not sure how to create a custom visualstate, but it sounds interesting..I look into that one